# How to fix this issue, System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException: No property or field asc exist in type 'TblEventsManagements'?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nt83n.png)I have this controller GetList and i am using Linq.Dynamic to filter for fields in the table be searched and this uses dataTable for server side processing. Who can help me to resolve this problem? Below is my logic and line where this error is thrown;

```
[\[HttpPost\]
   public ActionResult GetList()
    {
        //Server side Parameter.
        int start = Convert.ToInt32(Request\["start"\]);
        int length = Convert.ToInt32(Request\["length"\]);
        string searchValue = Request\["search\[value\]"\];
        string sortColumnName = Request\["columns\[" + Request\["order\[0\]\[column\]"\] + "\]\[name\]"\];
        string sortDirection = Request\["order\[0\]\[dir\]"\];


        using (eNtsaOnlineRegistrationDBContext db = new eNtsaOnlineRegistrationDBContext())
        {

            IQueryable<TblEventsManagements> empList = db.TblEventsManagements;
           int totalrows = empList.Count();
            int totalrowsafterfiltering = totalrows;


            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue))
            {
                empList = empList.Where(x => x.TrainingType.Contains(searchValue) || x.TrainingDescription.Contains(searchValue) || x.Price.ToString().Contains(searchValue.ToLower())
                || x.Venue.Contains(searchValue) || x.Facilitator.Contains(searchValue) || x.WhoAttend.Contains(searchValue) || x.Rsvp.Contains(searchValue));


            }


            empList = empList.OrderBy(sortColumnName + "" + sortDirection).Skip(start).Take(length);



            return Json(new { data = empList, draw = Request\["draw"\], recordsTotal = totalrows, recordsFiltered = totalrowsafterfiltering }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }



    }][1]
```

I forgot to put my Ajax call, i thought at first the issue was missing field from my table. Now i am getting field or type 'TrainingTypeasc' is not exist, well it does on my table from the database. Where can i improve this logic mates? Please help.

```
 <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

               $("#EventManagementTable").DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Dashboard/GetList",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "datatype":"json"
                },
                   "columns": [
                    {"data": "TrainingType", "name": "TrainingType"},
                    { "data": "TrainingDescription", "name": "TrainingDescription" },
                    { "data": "Price", "name": "Price" },
                    { "data": "Venue", "name": "Venue" },
                    { "data": "Facilitator", "name": "Facilitator" },
                    { "data": "WhoAttend", "name": "WhoAttend" },
                    {"data": "RSVP", "name": "RSVP"},
                ],

                "serverSide": "true",
                "order":[0,"asc"],
                "processing": "true",
                "language": {
                    "processing":"processing... please wait"
                }



            });

        });
```

Comment: what this mean(sortColumnName + "" + sortDirection)? Do you write an Extension for Order by?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this :

```
empList = empList.OrderBy(sortColumnName + "" + sortDirection).Skip(start).Take(length);
```

with this:

```
 empList = empList.OrderByPropertyName(sortColumnName,sortDirection).Skip(start).Take(length)
```

and add this to your project:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace "YourNameSpace"
{
    public static class ListExtension
    {
        public static IOrderedEnumerable<T>  OrderByPropertyName<T>(this ICollection<T> list, string sortColumnName, string sortDirection)
        {
            var type = typeof(T);

            var property = sortColumnName == "" ? type.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault() : type.GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name == sortColumnName).FirstOrDefault();

            return sortColumnName == "asc" ? list.OrderBy(p => property.GetValue(p)) : list.OrderByDescending(p => property.GetValue(p));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I update answer to check if argument is String.Empty

Comment: must this class be an independent object outside my MVC? im getting error on PropertyName and required some namespace or package. Please assist thanks.

Comment: you need to add System.Collections.Generic and System.Linq to your `using` list

Comment: Also, You can add this ctode to a new class file with the same name as class in anywhere that you want . but your controller must have access to this new class.

Comment: Why am i not getting an results back now Ali?

Comment: Have you any error or exception? i test code again ,it is doing job properly.

Comment: please see the attached screen shot of the output.

Comment: Unfortunately i cant take any info from screenshot. please put an break point on orderby line and check the value of sortColumnName  and sortDirection and then check the result of OrderByPropertyName method.